# ICEMobile : Packaging ICEMobile error in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, icefaces

I got this error when run ICEMobile demo on Blackberry :

An internal error occurred during: "Packaging ICEmobileContainer".

```
org.osgi.framework.Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to deploy [IceMobile](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEmobile/overview.jsf) directly onto a BlackBerry device?  It's meant to run on a web server, not directly on the device.  BlackBerry devices use Java-ME, so you will get some verification errors if you try to deploy Java-SE code.

> ICEmobile is an open source project for the development of web-based, Enterprise Java applications for mobile devices. Core mobile features are packaged in technology-specific bundles to enable mobile rich Internet application development across a wide spectrum of Enterprise Java technologies.